# Laravel Restful API, create and store Method

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently building a RESTful API. In my controller the `store` method I create the object and save it but for what should I use the `create` method? And how can I create my object in the `create` method? Which method do I have to call first and how can I give the parameters from method to method because I only have them in my `store` method?

I want to learn to program in a right and beautiful way, so that everyone can understand the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it’s a RESTful API then you don’t need a `create` method. In fact, in later versions of Laravel, if you make a controller with Artisan and pass the `--api` flag, then it’ll create a controller stubbed with methods, and none of them will be `create`: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/76fa2de90c438859f7c85718a98696fe7509c918/src/Illuminate/Routing/Console/stubs/controller.api.stub

Answer (score 0):

use the below links for Restful api creation:

https://www.toptal.com/laravel/restful-laravel-api-tutorial

Comment: why revert my edit? One link is 404!

Answer (score 0):

store is for saving the new model, create is to display the form/view to create the model.
Also edit is to show the edit from/view and update to save it.

Comment: and if i do not have a form/view, I get my data from a post request

Comment: then you can delete the method in controller and route  
`Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController')->except(['create', 'edit']);`